# Reading a text file column wise and count which column it is written in Python

Tags: python, string, list, text-files

A text file contains:

```
//     H HGD
//     i eoa
//       loy
//       ld
//       o
//       _
//       W
//       o
//       r
//       l
//       d
```

How can I put it on a list and add at which column it was written such that it outputs:
`[[<1st_word>,<location of the 1st word>],[<2nd_word>,<location of the 2nd word>],...]`

So far I have written a code (shown below), but I'am stuck:

```
file = open(text_file, "r")
wrd = ""
for line in file: #Each line from file
    for c in ln: #Each character in line
        if(c != ' ' or c != '\n' or c != '/'): #Ignore slashes (/), white spaces, and newlines
            #list = put word on a list and count at which column was found
            #print(list)
```

How can I put it on a list and add at which column it was written, such that it outputs:
`[[Hi,8],[Hello_World,10],[Good,11],[Day,12]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this way:

1. creating a dictionary of which characters are observed in what index
2. reformatting into the list format specified in the question

```
results = {}
with open(text_file, "r") as fp:    
    for line in fp:
        for idx, c in enumerate(line):
            if c not in [' ', '\n', '/', '\t']:
                if idx not in results.keys():
                    results[idx] = []
                results[idx].append(c)

print(results)
#Out[6]: 
#{7: ['H', 'i'],
# 9: ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '_', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
# 10: ['G', 'o', 'o', 'd'],
# 11: ['D', 'a', 'y']}

final_results = [[''.join(v), k+1] for k,v in results.items()]
print(final_results)
# Out[10]: [['Hi', 8], ['Hello_World', 10], ['Good', 11], ['Day', 12]]
```

If the text has tabs as well, you can use Textwrap to translate them into whitespace:

```
import textwrap
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper()

results = {}
with open(text_file, "r") as fp:    
    for line in fp:
        for idx, c in enumerate(wrapper.wrap(line)[0]):
            if c not in [' ', '\n', '/']:
                if idx not in results.keys():
                    results[idx] = []
                results[idx].append(c)

#{8: ['H', 'i'],
# 10: ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '_', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
# 11: ['G', 'o', 'o', 'd'],
# 12: ['D', 'a', 'y']}

final_results = [[''.join(v), k] for k,v in results.items()]
print(final_results)
#[['Hi', 8], ['Hello_World', 10], ['Good', 11], ['Day', 12]]
```

You can do it without list comprehension as well:

```
final_results = []
for idx, char_vals in results.items():
    word = ''.join(char_vals)
    final_results.append([word, idx])
print(final_results)
#[['Hi', 8], ['Hello_World', 10], ['Good', 11], ['Day', 12]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the numbering is wrong (output written below). Can you try avoiding list comprehension, as I am still new to Python and haven't figured out how to do list comprehension? I am also on Linux, I'm not sure if this could have influenced the results.

`{0: ['\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t', '\t'], 1: ['H', 'i'], 3: ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '_', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'], 4: ['G', 'o', 'o', 'd'], 5: ['D', 'a', 'y']}`
`[['\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', 1], ['Hi', 2], ['Hello_World', 4], ['Good', 5], ['Day', 6]]`

Comment: you can add '\t' to the list to avoid - I copied and paste your example file and there was no tab (\t). You can simply fix the '\t' problem but the number is the actual index of the characters in the line... you can do some messy work to count \t as a maximum of 4 spaces but I am not sure that' the path you want to take... btw, I will fix the '\t' problem in the answer.

Comment: I found a way to deal with '\t' characters - you need to normalize the text first, using textwrapper because \t is maximum 4 space but it could 1, 2, or 3 depending on its index in the string - I will update the code now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can form a list of column strings using zip_longest.

Then convert these columns to strings and strip the extra spaces to form a list of words.

Using enumerate in a comprehension will then allow you to get words along with their column numbers:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    columns  = zip_longest(*f.readlines(),fillvalue=" ")
    words    = map(str.strip,map("".join,columns))
    wordCols = [[w,i] for i,w in enumerate(words,1) if w and "/" not in w]

print(wordCols)
[['Hi', 8], ['Hello_World', 10], ['Good', 11], ['Day', 12]]
```